# Line Animation when Editing UITextField

Tags: swift, authentication, uitextfield, cashapelayer, caanimation

I'm trying to add animation to the border of UITextField when edited by the user. The idea is to show line animation in the login page once the first text field is being edited and then after the user switches to the next textfield, the line should make a movement to the below text field. I have made an attempt which is not working as what I'm expecting. The following is the code I'm using:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var verticSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTxtField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTxtField: UITextField!

weak var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer?

let path = UIBezierPath()

let shapeLayerNew = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    usernameTxtField.delegate = self

    passwordTxtField.delegate = self

}



func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    if textField == usernameTxtField {
        if textField.text == "" {

            self.startMyLine()
        }

    }

    if passwordTxtField.isFirstResponder {


        let path2 = UIBezierPath()


        path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: usernameTxtField.frame.width, y: usernameTxtField.frame.height - shapeLayerNew.lineWidth))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: usernameTxtField.frame.width, y: (usernameTxtField.frame.height - shapeLayerNew.lineWidth) + passwordTxtField.frame.height + verticSpace.constant))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: (usernameTxtField.frame.height - shapeLayerNew.lineWidth) + passwordTxtField.frame.height + verticSpace.constant))


        let combinedPath = path.cgPath.mutableCopy()
        combinedPath?.addPath(path2.cgPath)
        shapeLayerNew.path = path2.cgPath


        let startAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
        startAnimation.fromValue = 0
        startAnimation.toValue = 0.8

        let endAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        endAnimation.fromValue = 0.2
        endAnimation.toValue = 1.0

        let animation = CAAnimationGroup()
        animation.animations = [startAnimation, endAnimation]
        animation.duration = 2
        shapeLayerNew.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")


    }



}

func startMyLine() {

    self.shapeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    // create whatever path you want


    shapeLayerNew.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
    shapeLayerNew.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    shapeLayerNew.lineWidth = 4


    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: usernameTxtField.frame.height - shapeLayerNew.lineWidth))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: usernameTxtField.frame.width, y: usernameTxtField.frame.height - shapeLayerNew.lineWidth))



    // create shape layer for that path



    shapeLayerNew.path = path.cgPath

    // animate it

    usernameTxtField.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayerNew)

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.duration = 2
    shapeLayerNew.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")

    // save shape layer

    self.shapeLayer = shapeLayerNew


}
```

}

And this is the result I'm getting:

[image: My Attempt]

And this is what I need to see:

[image: What I'm expecting]

Comment: second photo from which app on apple store  or this your prototype

Comment: This is the work of an amazing designer I found on Behance. His name is Jakub Antalik. Will appreciate it if you can help

Comment: i work on , will update as soon as possible

Comment: Any updates for me?